# Python: convert pandas DataFrame to dict of lists

Tags: python, json, pandas, transformation

I need to convert this DataFrame:

```
meterid    timestamp                  value
123       2018-04-09T21:34:55.335Z     0
123       2018-05-10T21:34:55.335Z     10
456       2018-04-09T21:34:55.335Z     200
```

to this format:

```
{
   "data":{
      "123":[
         [
            "2018-04-09T21:34:55.335Z",
            0
         ],
         [
            "2018-05-10T21:34:55.335Z",
            10
         ]
      ],
      "456":[
         [
            "2018-04-09T21:34:55.335Z",
            200
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

What is the best way of transforming this? I tried `to.dict()` with different values of `orient`, but it didn't give me what I wanted. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hacky, but you could do iterrow and store in a dictionary:

```
data_store = dict()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if data_store.get(row["meterid"]):
        data_store[row["meterid"]] = row["timestamp" : ].tolist()
    else:
        data_store[row["meterid"]] = []
        data_store[row["meterid"]] = row["timestamp" : ].tolist()
```

Would give problems if meterid is not unique, but if it is, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would combine all the data columns into 1 column with the code below:

```
df["combined"] = df.drop("meterid", axis=1).values.tolist()
```

Then I would use the code below to produce the output you specified:

```
df[["meterid", "combined"]].groupby("meterid")["combined"].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Since the meterid in the prompt is not unique, I've written this code with the assumption that the meterid is not the index of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

`dict((df.index[i],df.iloc[i,1:].to_list()) for i in range(len(df)))`

as a quick and dirty option.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.set_index("meterid").apply(lambda ss:ss.tolist(),axis=1)\
    .groupby(level=0).agg(list).to_dict()
```

out:

```
{123: [['2018-04-09T21:34:55.335Z', 0], ['2018-05-10T21:34:55.335Z', 10]],
 456: [['2018-04-09T21:34:55.335Z', 200]]}
```